# In R with VSCode, running a single function with browser() or debug() does not evoke debugging environment

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, debugging

There have been some guides elaborating on how to use `vscDebugger` to set an interactive debugging environment for R in VSCode :

- [VSCode marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RDebugger.r-debugger)
- [Debugging R in VSCode](https://renkun.me/about/)

However, the debugging environment provided by `vscDebugger` is only evoked when we run the whole script through the VSCode's *Run and Debug* interface. In Rstudio, by contrast, the interactive debug mode also occurs when you independently run from the console a function that contains a `browser()` or has been `debug()`ed. Doing the same in VSCode only leads to a command-line debugging procedure without an interactive interface. I wonder whether we can configure VSCode to approximate Rstudio in debugging.

The following are some of my VSCode debugger settings (just default settings coming with the fresh installation):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Launch R-Workspace",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "workspace",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Debug R-File",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "file",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "file": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Debug R-Function",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "function",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "file": "${file}",
            "mainFunction": "main",
            "allowGlobalDebugging": false
        },
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "name": "Debug R-Package",
            "request": "launch",
            "debugMode": "workspace",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "includePackageScopes": true,
            "loadPackages": [
                "."
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "R-Debugger",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to R process",
            "splitOverwrittenOutput": true
        }
    ]
}
```